# Does the symbol on the bodies of the damned have any real-world significance?

Tags: jigoku-shoujo

In Hell Girl, when someone condemns their target to be banished to Hell immediately, they forfeit their own afterlife in Heaven as the price. As a mark of this covenant between the cursee and Hell Girl herself, a black mark appears upon their chest, shown in the pictures below:

[image]

[image]

Does this symbol have any significance outside the show? Or is it simply a fictional one to represent Hell in the series?

Comment: This is just a speculation, but it resembles a [mitsudomoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomoe). Some view the mitsudomoe as representative of the threefold division (Man, Earth, and Sky) at the heart of the Shinto religion.